# Matplotlib module not found despite being present in conda env list

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, import, anaconda

I'm running vscode on windows with anaconda. All packages I've tried importing including pandas,sys, os work fine. Except one.

When I run conda list this is my output which includes matplotlib:

```
.
.
libxslt                   1.1.37               h2bbff1b_0
libzlib                   1.2.13               hcfcfb64_5    intel
matplotlib                3.7.1           py310haa95532_1
matplotlib-base           3.7.1           py310h4ed8f06_1
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6           py310haa95532_0
mkl                       2023.2.0            intel_49496    intel
.
.
```

Trying to import the module to use in vscode gives me the error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tarus\pyenvs\epictardownloader.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\tarus\anaconda3\envs\housingenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\tarus\anaconda3\envs\housingenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "C:\Users\tarus\anaconda3\envs\housingenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 51, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Users\tarus\anaconda3\envs\housingenv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 103, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've tried reinstalling the package several times with several different versions, reinstalling vscode, making a new conda environment and installing the packages there, reinstalling with pip. None of it worked. I really can't think of anything else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the stack trace, the problem is with PIL (pillow library).
Perhaps you can try to (re)install that one manually